# Nonnegative Permanent and Ellipsoidal Method

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms

Famously, Barahona gave an algorithm for Max Cut for Graphs without K5 complete as Subfactor Graph.

This was based on the Ellipsoidal Method.

Finding a Max Cut is the same for Bipartite Graphs as finding a Perfect Matching. Therefore, is seems to me that if you could Count the solutions to Barahona Ellipsoidal Method, you could have fast fpras for Nonnegative Permanent!

Question: Has any work been done in this direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand why finding a max cut is the same for bipartite graphs as finding a perfect matching.  A max cut for bipartite graphs is trivial: a proper 2-coloring gives a max cut.

Comment: [Nonnative permanent already has an FPRAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Approximate_computation)